# Caching a link to another page with service worker

Tags: javascript, html, caching, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I am looking to cache the contents of a dynamic linked page. I have a simple index.html with a service worker registered, and want to set it up where when you reach this page it dynamically caches the contents that the link is pointing to (the idea is that this second page will not be included in the static install event).

Basically I am designing a page that will have a link to a recommended/related page which I want to be stored in the cache. When the user clicks the link to the recommended related page I want it to load from the cache.

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    <h3>I want to cache</h3>
    <a href="page2.html">this link to my second page!</a> 
  <script>
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js').then(function(reg) {
        // registration worked
        console.log('Registration succeeded. Scope is ' + reg.scope);
      }).catch(function(error) {
        // registration failed
        console.log('Registration failed with ' + error);
      });
    }
  </script>
  </body>    
</html>
```

page2.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script2.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>This is my second page!</h1>
    <h3>I want everything from this page to be stored in the cache.</h3>
  </body> 
</html>
```

Here is the plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/YIAacgkuboyRBkv10hfl?p=catalogue

How can I set up my fetch event to dynamically cache the contents of the second page without explicitly putting page2.html in my static install event?

Comment: please explain the "dynamic" wording with better description, like when and how will it be cached? On hover, click or ready event. Cache it once time only or all the time #1 page loaded...

Comment: Basically I am designing a page that will have a link to a recommended page which I want to be stored in the cache. When the user clicks this link to the recommended related page I want it to load from the cache.

Comment: Basically you want to emulate browser [prefetch](https://davidwalsh.name/html5-prefetch) with service workers?

Comment: If you can send dynamic link info in static page header you can then read it from fetch event response. Else, you can try and parse response.text() for dynamic links.

Comment: @TeoDragovic I basically want to emulate that yes. I wan't to advertise this related/recommended page as something that can be loaded almost instantaneously from the cache, and will work offline. What will response.text() do for me in this instance?

Comment: It will return stringified version of your static page HTML. You can use that to extract your dynamic links inside sw but it's hacky solution. That's why I think it's better to add dynamic pages data in req. header from the backend if possible.

Comment: @TeoDragovic do you think there is a way to use sw-toolbox to achieve what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 2):

According to your updated question, you could do it with the [**Client.postMessage()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Client/postMessage).

In your client/html/script

```
<a href="/url/cache-this" class="precache"></a>
<script>
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {

  // ensure service worker is ready, you can also put this into DOM 'ready' or 'load' event
  navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(function (reg) {

    var data = {
      action: "precache", 
      url: $('.precache').attr('href') // if you had more than an url need to be cached, do a loop to collect all data
    };
    // NOTE: the 'action' is optional, but it is nice to separate your message type, in case you have a lot of communication between DOM and service worker.

    // message to SW a stringified string of data.
    navigator.serviceWorker.controller.postMessage(JSON.stringify(data));

  });
}
</script>
```

In your service worker.

```
self.addEventListener('message', event => {

  if (event.data) { 
    let data = JSON.parse(event.data); // parse the message back to JSON
    if (data.action == "precache") { // check the action
        self.toolbox.precache([data.url]); // here you can use sw-toolbox or anything to cache your stuff.
    }
  }
});
```

**EDIT:** fixed typos

Comment: so in this case it I would literally only be caching the link itself - so the page wouldn't work offline unless I manually added every item that needed to be cached in the data variable?

Comment: yes, you still need to tell what should SW cache for you. Because SW only work in 2 cases --- 1. you tell it what it should precache --- 2. listen to out going ajax requests and cache accordingly. → In your case, you can only use first option.

Comment: so imagining my second page that I want to precache is large with multiple images/text/etc. what are you imagining this loop looking like that will collect all data?

Comment: Yes, it will work, but you can do it in this way, or the other ways around. It is all about your preferring. For example you don't necessary need to put data in HTML, instead just put in JS of first page, or get the data from a server then send it to SW, or use `fetch` in SW and get the data. As you can see `toolbox.precache()`  taking an array as its first param. So we just need to give it an array of urls, and all will be cached. --- But beware of performance issue, if you are telling SW to cache 10 images with 2MB each, your browser will download 20MB data for the caching process.

Comment: so if I were to use the example you gave above where I just grab the url and precache that - would that effectively cache that entire page?

Comment: EDIT: cache HTML content, yes. Entire page(css/js), no. You still need to tell SW what exactly it should cache, as mentioned above --- SW made for single-page webapp, if you use it outside of the box, you need to put more efforts.

Comment: I followed, your steps to send messages to service worker. But for me, the service worker is never ready. I checked for issues with scoping. My service-worker.js is at root of the directory.

Answer (score 0):

incase your link destination has pattern like a "yoursite/pages/" you can put toolbox cache router for that

```
toolbox.router.get('/myapp/pages/*', toolbox.networkFirst);
```

This is another solution for dynamic cache